# Cast web control to html control with in master page

Tags: vb.net, master-pages

I'm trying to clean up some existing VB code.  Issue is I've created a master page and trying to using a already created user control with in the content holder  of the master page.  I've attached a image of the error

[image].
I'm not exactly sure how to cast this with in VB.

Here is the code that is causing the error.

```
            --->Dim myPage As HtmlControls.HtmlForm = Me.Parent
        Dim myParent As Page = myPage.Parent
        If myParent.ToString.Contains("private_accountinfo") AndAlso prevPage.Contains("Default_Login") Then
            pnlMenu.Visible = False
        ElseIf myParent.ToString.Contains("default_support") And Session("Utente") = "" Then
            pnlMenu.Visible = False
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the page or the placeholder? (The variable says myPage, but you're after a placeholder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is in your error message. You have a `ContentPlaceHolder`, but you're dimming it as an `HtmlForm`. Don't do that. Use:

`Dim myPage As HtmlControls.ContentPlaceHolder = Me.Parent`